# Getting $_GET to work with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

I've seen several examples but i can't seem to get it working.

Config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";  
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Library:

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input  
{  
    function _sanitize_globals()  
    {  
        $this->allow_get_array = TRUE;  
        parent::_sanitize_globals();  
    }  
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Input');  
..................  

$sid=$this->input->get('sid',TRUE);  
$name=$this->input->get('name',TRUE);  
$campid=$this->input->get('campid',TRUE);  
$rate=$this->input->get('rate',TRUE);  
$status=$this->input->get('status',TRUE);
```

Here's the url:

```
www.mysite.com/memb/index/postback.php?campid=23552342&name=mcamp&rate=15&sid=42&status=1&ip=198152999000
```

What happens is that it just goes to my home page and doesn't update the db and it doesn't go to the test view page i added in the controller just to see if would load a view.

Edit: Now it seems that if i try to load other views i always end in the home view...

Answer (score 1):

put this in your controller

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

Then you can use your $_GET variables like normal... ie.  echo $_GET['var']

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is open the **application/config/config.php** file, then:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z ? 0-9~%.:_\-';
```